# Обращение к COM-объекту внутри сервиса

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, com

Есть приложение, которое создаёт COM-объект и является сервером, принимающим соединения. Клиентские программы успешно подключаются/запускают этот сервер и получают доступ к данным.

После дополнения функциями win сервиса, с регистрацией у менеджера и возможностью остановки/запуска, стало невозможно обратиться к COM-объекту, который создаётся внутри теперь уже сервиса.

COM-объект создаётся внутри статической библиотеки, которая используется сервером.

В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: У Вас есть три варианта - сервис не запускается совсем, - сервис не создает(не может создать) COM, -  COM поменял "место жительства" - сменился guid, права и тому подобное.

Comment: Я, скорее всего, не совсем правильно сформулировал вопрос. Для определённости - то, что я хочу поместить в сервис является OPC-сервером. COM-объект во всех необходимых местах прописывается. Когда к нему хочет подключиться OPC-клиент, то он это сделать не может. В реестре лежит путь к `exe` сервиса. Он пытается его запутить и ничего не происходит. Как-то так.

Comment: То есть, клиент пытается запустить ехе, который уже не соответствует соглашению (он то уже сервис). Похоже, Вам нужно будет и клиент переписать.

Comment: Я пробовал в реестре исправить способ запуска - т.е. запуск с параметром, который бы запускал сервис, если тот не запущен. Т.е. просто из командной строки это срабатывало.

Comment: А если сервис запустить, то код работает?

Comment: Да, работает. Регистрируется и пишет в лог.

Comment: *"В реестре лежит путь к exe сервиса."* - где?

Comment: Не хочется вводить в заблуждение - под рукой нет того компьютера. Мне кажется, что в LocalServer

Comment: @user1056837 ага, вот и ошибка нашлась...

Comment: А какой должен быть? inprocServer32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of process server надо по-разному прописывать в реестре в зависимости от того, хостится он в обычном приложении или в службе.

Для обычного приложения надо указывать ключ `CLSID\{CLSID}\LocalServer32\@`

Для сервиса - надо указывать `CLSID\{CLSID}\AppID`, который ссылается на `AppID\{AppID}\LocalService32`

И не забудьте дать права на запуск сервиса всем пользователям.